# Google Services Authentication Google_IO_Exception with message 'Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: php, api, youtube

I am using Youtube data api its properly working on localhost but when I am trying to access this code on live server its not working. giving an exception :

> Uncaught exception 'Google_IO_Exception' with message 'Protocol
>   "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl' in
>   /home/legenddude/public_html/newUpload/Google/IO/Curl.php:115 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   /home/legenddude/public_html/newUpload/Google/IO/Abstract.php(136):
>   Google_IO_Curl->executeRequest(Object(Google_Http_Request)) #1
>   /home/legenddude/public_html/newUpload/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php(111):
>   Google_IO_Abstract->makeRequest(Object(Google_Http_Request)) #2
>   /home/legenddude/public_html/newUpload/Google/Client.php(128):
>   Google_Auth_OAuth2->authenticate('4/x7_AOHFKvmlea...', false) #3
>   /home/legenddude/public_html/newUpload/youtube.php(44):
>   Google_Client->authenticate('4/x7_AOHFKvmlea...') #4 {main} thrown in

Here is my code youtube.php-:

```
<?php
 // Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
set_include_path($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/newUpload/');

require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
/*
 * You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
 * {{ Google Cloud Console }} <{{ https://cloud.google.com/console }}>
 * For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs, please see:
 * <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
 * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
 */
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '619899784025-5nn2tqomt3cr6g231qd93nr0lsojdvq9.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = '49K6Ou9PK9n1aamAeg27fnIC';
$REDIRECT = 'http://www.legenddude.com/newUpload/youtube.php';
$APPNAME = "legenddudes";


$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube");
$client->setRedirectUri($REDIRECT);
$client->setApplicationName($APPNAME);
$client->setAccessType('online');
$client->setDeveloperKey('619899784025-5nn2tqomt3cr6g231qd93nr0lsojdvq9@developer.gserviceaccount.com');


// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
        die('The session state did not match.');
    }
   //echo $_SESSION['state'];exit;
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    echo '<code>' . $_SESSION['token'] . '</code>';
}

// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    try {
        // Call the channels.list method to retrieve information about the
        // currently authenticated user's channel.
        $channelsResponse = $youtube->channels->listChannels('contentDetails', array(
            'mine' => 'true',
        ));

        $htmlBody = '';
        foreach ($channelsResponse['items'] as $channel) {
            // Extract the unique playlist ID that identifies the list of videos
            // uploaded to the channel, and then call the playlistItems.list method
            // to retrieve that list.
            $uploadsListId = $channel['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads'];

            $playlistItemsResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('snippet', array(
                'playlistId' => $uploadsListId,
                'maxResults' => 50
            ));

            $htmlBody .= "<h3>Videos in list $uploadsListId</h3><ul>";
            foreach ($playlistItemsResponse['items'] as $playlistItem) {
                $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>', $playlistItem['snippet']['title'],
                    $playlistItem['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']);
            }
            $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
        }
    } catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
        $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
            htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
    } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
        $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
            htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
    }

    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
    $state = mt_rand();
    $client->setState($state);
    $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorise access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Uploads</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $htmlBody?>
</body>
</html>`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

From [curl_faq](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Protocol_xxx_not_supported_or_di):

> When passing on a URL to curl to use, it may respond that the particular protocol is not supported or disabled. The particular way this error message is phrased is because curl doesn't make a distinction internally of whether a particular protocol is not supported (i.e. never got any code added that knows how to speak that protocol) or if it was explicitly disabled. curl can be built to only support a given set of protocols, and the rest would then be disabled or not supported.

And more:

> To get the https:// support into a curl that was previously built but that reports that https:// is not supported, you should dig through the document and logs and check out why the configure script doesn't find the SSL libs and/or include files.